# JavaFX audio "BUZZ" when video starts

Tags: audio, javafx, media-player, fxml

I'm using JavaFX for creating a Video Player, and it's almost done.
But sometimes, when the video starts, its audio starts with an hard "BUZZ" sound.

I can't make you listen, but maybe there is someone who has already faced this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found the cause of this issue...that was the Mac OSX environment, due to his codecs. I switched to windows and the problem never appeared again.